# Superconformal Multiplet Calculus in 6D

Tags: particle-physics, research-level, superconformality, supergravity

A convenient method for dealing with off-shell formulations of
supergravity theories is provided by the superconformal multiplet
calculus. This calculus was originally constructed for 4d ${\cal N}=2$
supergravity by de Wit et al.  For 5d supergravity,
conformal supergravity approach was developed relatively recently by several
groups of Bergshoeff et al, Ohashi et al,Hanaki et al.

http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/hep-th/0104113 ,
http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/hep-th/0104130 ,
http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/hep-th/0611329 .

The main idea is that  the Poincare algebra is extended to the superconformal algebra to obtain an off-shell version of Poincare supergravity. It turns out that extending conformal supergravity to a gauge theory of superconformal algebra provides an irreducible off-shell realization of the gravity and matter multiplets. Then, by imposing constraints, the gauge theory is identified as a gravity theory. Upon gauge fixing the extra superconformal symmetries, one obtains  the Poincare supergravity. In this formalism, 
one has a systematic way to construct invariant actions since the transformation laws are simpler and completely fixed by the superconformal algebra. Following this approach, one gets an off-shell formulation of supergravity coupled to vector multiplets.

As far as I know, there is no off-shell formulation of 6d supergravity by superconformal multiplet calculas. Why is there no conformal supergravity in 6D? Is there any obstruction to the formulation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Satoshi, I know of one paper which does this: "Nucl Phys B 264, Superconformal tensor calculus and matter couplings in six dimensions, Pages 653-686, E. Bergshoeff, E. Sezgin, A. Van Proeyen"

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. How about different supersymmetry? Namely ${\cal N}=(2,0)$ and ${\cal N}=(1,1)$?